# Replace / after a patter is match using SED command

Tags: shell-script, sed

I have this command where I need to update the **/** only after **pt -d**, it should be replaced by **"%2F"**.

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' 'http://abc.abc:8080/api/server/sendUnixCommand?command=pt' -d "/abc/abc/abc/abc-abc/abc/abc/" ls
```

I am new to this so a help with really appreciated.

Also wanted to highlight that the above entire curl command will be part of a variable so I cannot split it. It will be a one long string for which i need to replace **/** only after **pt' -d**

Comment: Can't you use [`--data-urlencode`](https://everything.curl.dev/http/post/url-encode) instead of `-d`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sed pattern you can use is:

```
sed 's|/|%2F|g'
```

This means: "*s*ubstitute `/` with `%2F` globally".  In sed, you ususally see the `s/foo/bar/g` syntax, but the delimiter can be other characters too.  To avoid escaping the `/`, I used a `|` instead.

To integrate this into your command (using `bash`) you can use a subshell.

```
curl \
  -X GET \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  'http://abc.abc:8080/api/server/sendUnixCommand?command=pt' \
  -d "$(sed 's|/|%2F|g' <<< "/abc/abc/abc/abc-abc/abc/abc/")" \
  ls
```

In this case, I put `$(sed 's|/|%2F|g' <<< "/abc/abc/...")` where your old argument needs replacing.

In your comment you say that you want this to be in a variable.  That is possible.  In this case I achieve that by simply escaping the spaces outside of the subshell:

```
$ VAR=curl\ -X\ GET\ --header\ 'Accept: application/json'\ 'http://abc.abc:8080/api/server/sendUnixCommand?command=pt'\ -d\ "$(sed 's|/|%2F|g' <<< "/abc/abc/abc/abc-abc/abc/abc/")"\ ls
$ echo $VAR
curl -X GET --header Accept: application/json http://abc.abc:8080/api/server/sendUnixCommand?command=pt -d %2Fabc%2Fabc%2Fabc%2Fabc-abc%2Fabc%2Fabc%2F ls
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but wanted to highlight that the above entire curl command will be part of a variable so I cannot split it that the issue . So i want to change the / ONLY after pt -d

Comment: I haven't "split" the command.  The newlines are only inserted (prefixed with `\\` ) for readability.  I added an example of inserting this into a variable at the end of the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Stewart I had to do some tweaks in my code to adapt your changes but what you suggested helped a lot.